# Please explain the meaning of '!' in context to a function call

Tags: swift

I read a code where it was written 'readLine()!'. What is the meaning of '!' at the end of a function call. I tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You can always access the result of a returning function directly and as explained below this is for force unwrapping the returned optional but you can also access properties or call other functions on the returned type, like `readLine()?.lowercased()` to get the result as an optional all lowercase string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641199-readline/) of `readLine()` states, the return value of the function is an `Optional` `String`. So the `!` right after the function call simply force unwraps the optional return value.

```
let optionalInput: String? = readLine()
let forceUnwrappedInput: String = readLine()!
```

Beware that force unwrapping an `Optional` value results in a runtime exception if the force unwrapped value was `nil`, so you should be very careful with using it and should only do force unwrapping if you are 100% sure that the value can never be `nil`.

Comment: Yes, that explains it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

'!' is the simplest but most dangerous way to extract the value of the `Optionals`.
Optionals indicates that there may or may not be a value.

You can extract a value by pasting '!' after the 'Optionals' value, but if there is no value, a `runtime error` occurs.

so, you'd better use 'Optional Binding' to extract values.

```
let optionalInput: String? = readLine()
if input = optionalInput {
// When nil is not

   ... 

} else {
// When nil
  ...

}
```